# How to connect SqlDelight driver to Multiplatform Kotlin Library?

Tags: sqlite, kotlin

I want to write a simple ORM on Kotlin Native. I'm creating a project in the Multiplatform Library studio. Found the Sql Delight driver. According to the documentation, I'm trying to install it. But nothing comes out. How to connect SqlDelight driver to Multiplatform Kotlin Library?

Here is my gradle.wrappers:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.1-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform' version '1.3.41'
}

repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}

group 'com.example.test'
version '0.0.1'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'com.squareup.sqldelight'

archivesBaseName = 'store-item'

configurations {
    compileClasspath
}
kotlin {
    jvm()

    sourceSets {
        commonMain {
            dependencies {
                implementation kotlin('stdlib-common')
            }
        }
        commonTest {
            dependencies {
                implementation kotlin('test-common')
                implementation kotlin('test-annotations-common')
            }
        }
        jvmMain {
            dependencies {
                implementation kotlin('stdlib-jdk8')
                implementation "com.squareup.sqldelight:sqlite-driver:1.1.4"
            }

        }
        jvmTest {
            dependencies {
                implementation kotlin('test')
                implementation kotlin('test-junit')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Gradle writes: Plugin with id 'com.squareup.sql delight' not found.

Answer (score 0):

The first step in [the SQLDelight docs](https://cashapp.github.io/sqldelight/multiplatform_sqlite/) is to set up the Gradle plugin.

By default Gradle will only search the Gradle Plugin Portal for plugins. But the SQLDelight Gradle plugin isn't published to Gradle Plugin Portal, it's published to Maven Central.

You need to [add config to tell Gradle to search Maven Central for Gradle plugins](https://docs.gradle.org/7.6/userguide/plugins.html#sec:custom_plugin_repositories).

However, you are on an old version of Gradle - 5.6. The current version of SQLDelight is 1.5.4, which is only compatible with Gradle 7+. You'll need to [update your version of Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/7.6/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html#sec:upgrading_wrapper).